# How do I correctly use multiple instances of the infer keyword with template literal types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I'm having trouble understanding a specific behaviour of `infer` , more specifically multiple occurrences of `infer` , within Template Literal Types. While looking for a type that would convert the keys of a type from snake_case to camelCase, I found an implementation that uses behaviour I don't see covered [in the typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#inference-with-template-literals). Here is the code I found:

```
type Test = 
{
    'hello_there': string;
    'another_snake_case': number;
};

type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> =
  S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ?
  `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` :
  S;

  const test = makeWatchedObject({test: number})

// Provide an input type, ensure its an object
// Loop through each key of the type, cast it to be SnakeToCamelCase using the as keyword.
// K in this case can be a string, symbol or number so do this fancy magic of & string to stop typescript complaining
// Then make the type the case as the one in the objecy
type OutputType<InputType extends Record<string, unknown>> = {[K in keyof InputType as SnakeToCamelCase<K & string>]: InputType[K]}

type CamelCaseOutput = OutputType<Test>;
```

I can follow how this works. My issue is with this part: `` S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` `` . Where S = 'another_snake_case, T will = 'another' and U will = 'snake_case'. I can find no reference to this behaviour of essentially pattern matching with multiple inferences being possible in any of the documentation I've seen.

I've looked online, searched through other questions and the official documentation and found no other explanations or examples. I'm fairly sure I've now worked out how this behaviour works based on this example, but it's frustrating to not read up on it further with official documentation.

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? You posted some code, and have stated "I'm fairly sure I've now worked out how this behaviour works". So I'm not really sure how to provide an answer here.

Comment: From [ms/TS#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336), "a placeholder followed by a literal character span is matched by inferring zero or more characters from the source until the first occurrence of that literal character span in the source".  That means `infer` captures are *non-greedy* (they only take the minimum length solution).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @AlexWayne Apologies, that was supposed to say "I'm fairly sure I've now worked out how this behaviour works **in this example**".

Basically I was able to determine what was happening in this case purely by following the code, but that wasn't teaching me exactly why it works like this which is why I was looking for further documentation.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. This appears to be missing in the typescript documentation

Comment: I didn't want to digress in my answer, but TS folks consider the release notes and github issues to be part of their documentation; and the TS4.1 release notes point to the PR which has the info you want.  And there's unfortunately no official language spec because the language moves too quickly and they don't have people to maintain such a document properly (see [ms/TS#15711](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15711)). So while it might be frustrating that there isn't a single location for the info you seek, it's apparently this way on purpose.  ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I've come to realise that since you posted. I wasn't aware at the time that that was the case. Thanks again for your input, you helped me out a lot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336), the PR that implemented [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) as [introduced in TypeScript 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types):

> Inference proceeds by matching each placeholder to a substring in the source from left to right: **A placeholder followed by a literal character span is matched by inferring zero or more characters from the source until the first occurrence of that literal character span in the source.** [emphasis added] A placeholder immediately followed by another placeholder is matched by inferring a single character from the source.

That means when performing [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) like `` S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? ⋯ : ⋯ ``, `T` will capture the minimum amount of the string as possible, stopping just before the first occurrence of the "`_`" character.  In other words, pattern matching before a literal character span is [lazy or non-greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching).

(Slight aside: pattern matching in template literal types isn't *completely* lazy, though.  As mentioned in the quoted text above: pattern matching before another placeholder, like `` S extends `${infer T}${infer U}` ? ⋯ : ⋯ ``, will grab exactly one character.  That means it is just *mostly lazy* or *a little bit greedy* in such cases. If it were consistently lazy, the first placeholder would only capture the empty string.  The reason for the inconsistency is to allow template literal types to be used to parse strings character-by-character.)